# How to fill classes with data from database

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I created two classes in my example. These classes represent respectively *{Author}* and *{BlogPost}*. I know how to fetch and write information from/to these classes. My question is about processing information from a database.

Do properties have to fetch data from a database class? The problem is I don't know how to fill a class with data from my database. The connection with the database isn't the problem. It is all about the way I can fill the class with data from my database.

```
<?php

class Author{

    private $naam;
    private $biografie;
    private $avatar;

public function getNaam() {
    print($this->naam);
}

public function getBiografie() {
    print($this->biografie);
}

public function getAvatar() {
    print($this->avatar);
}

public function setNaam($naam) {
    $this->naam = $naam;
}

public function setBiografie($biografie) {
    $this->biografie = $biografie;
}

public function setAvatar($avatar) {
    $this->avatar = $avatar;
}

}

class BlogPost{

    private $titel;
    private $content;
    private $author;

public function __construct() {
    $this->author = new Author;
}

public function getTitel() {
    print($this->titel);
}

public function getContent() {
    print($this->content);
}

public function getAuthor() {
    print($this->author->getNaam());
}

public function setTitel($titel) {
    $this->titel = $titel;
}

public function setContent($content) {
    $this->content = $content;
}

}

?>
```

I know how to get data from my database by writing queries, but I don't know to proces the data in my class.

Do I have to link my properties to the database?

```
private $naam = Database::getName();
```

Or do I need to write a query in my get or set method?

Comment: Show us the code you use to get the data from your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of different approaches to do this. Read about ActiveRecord or the Repository pattern. Personnaly, I prefer to leave persistence concerns out of the business layer, so I'm leaning towards the Repository pattern.

Repositories are often backed by your ORM of choice, but one could still be implemented in plain SQL. However, keep in mind that you will have to perform your own dirty checking to figure out which parts of your objects have changed when saving them if you do this without a tool.

Pseudocode for a repository:

```
public class AuthorSqlRepository implements AuthorRepository {
    private QueryService queryService;

    public AuthorSqlRepository(QueryService queryService) {
        this.queryService = queryService;
    }

    public void save(Author author) {}

    public Author findById(String authorId) {
        resultset = queryService.executeQuery('SELECT id, naam, bio, avatar FROM Author WHERE ...');

        author = new Author();

        //In languages that supports it, reflection can be used
        //to set private class members directly so that you do not need
        //public setters.
        author.setId(resultset.id);
        ...
        return author;
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
authorRepository = new AuthorSqlRepository(queryService);
author = authorRepository.findById(someAuthorId);
naam = author.getNaam();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private naam = Database::getName();
```

You can do something like this in Java, but not in PHP. If you do, PHP will throw a fatal error indicating invalid syntax.

You can only populate class properties by results of function calls, from within class methods only. For example:

```
class Author
{
    public $name;

    public function load()
    {
       $this->name = DB::getName();
    }
}

$author = new Author();
$author->load();
echo $author->name;
```

Also, as a best practice you should always name your methods and classes in English language only.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for using Dutch in stead of English in my parameter. 
It works for me, but I want to know if your example is an accepted and elegant way to do this?

Comment: @Lycaon That would pretty much fall in the ActiveRecord category, but there are other ways to do this. I prefer the Repository pattern.

Comment: @Lycaon What I dislike with this approach is that your objects may be left in an invalid state at any time. If load() is not called then the class members aren't correctly initialized. I strongly advise you to have always-valid entities rather than using objects as dumb data containers.

Comment: @plalx And what if I use a constructer instead of the function load?

Comment: @Lycaon Of course you can put that into constructor if you want to ensure it gets called when a class is instantiated.

Comment: @Lycaon You could always do that and deal with new entities (perhaps those without an id) differently when they get instanciated, but personnaly I find that active record violates the SRP. The role of business object is to protect it's invariants and represent a specific business concept as well as encapsulate behaviors related to that concept. Persistence is another concern that can easily be factored out...

Comment: @plalx That's a very known fact is that, the AR by its definition violates the SRP. Talking about persistence layers, coming down to the definition of Model layer itself, which goes far beyond his question. Also what you call `Repository` looks as a plain `Data Mapper` object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to build correct sql tables that suits your needs, which I assume you did already. 
In this case You probable have at least 2 tables : blogPosts & authors, where blogPosts.author used to join the author through it's id.

Second step you need to request needed data from DB, through INNER JOIN between those table, it can be written in many ways. for example if you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  you can do like this:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=your_host;dbname=your_db_name","your_user_name", "your_password");


$query=$db->query("SELECT a.naam, a.biografie, a.avatar, bp.title, bp.content, bp.author
                    FROM authors AS a, blogposts AS bp
                    WHERE a.id=bp.author");//Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object
```

Third, you need to fetch that data with one of fetching methods, for example fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) [PDO fetch method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
which converts the received data to php associative array a.k.a Dictionary(Swift,Python, etc...) and iterate over it like this:

```
while($r=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
//$r["naam"] for author's naam column 
//$r["title"] for blogPosts's title 
$bPost=new BlogPost();
$bPost->setTitle($r["title"]);
//...

}
```

As @DavidY  mentioned before, all names of Types,Methods,Properties,etc.. should be written in English and should be meaningful and also, note that in class BlogPost you wrote titel instead of title. Those little things can cause big bugs later.

Oh and one more thing, since you objects has a direct connection (Tight coupling), I would suggest to remove the public setters, and instead of that to initialize from constructor's parameters. Like this:

```
class BlogPost{
    private $title;
    private $content;
    private $author;
    public function __construct($title,$content,$author){
        $this->title=$title;
        $this->content=$content;
        $this->author=$author;
    }
}
class Author{
    private $naam;
    private $biografie;
    private $avatar;
    public function __construct($naam,$biografie,$avatar){
        $this->naam=$naam;
        $this->biografie=$biografie;
        $this->avatar=$avatar;
    }
}
```

Then your loop body become a single line

```
while($r=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $bPost=new BlogPost($r["title"],$r["content"],new Author($r["naam"],$r["biografie"],$r["avatar"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data from my database write sql queries and then use mysql_query or PDO as you know how to establish a connection

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I know how to get data from my database by writing queries, but I don't know to proces the data in my class.

Do I have to link my properties to the database? 
        private $naam = Database::getName();

Or do I need to write a query in my get or set method?

Comment: first write query,fetch data and then process them inside the class